# What does "Battles Won" refer to?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have just seen this on the top Pokémon on a gym. This is the first time I've seen it, so I'm not sure if it can/should apply to all Pokémon in the gym, or just the top.

[image: Battles Won: 1]

What does this mean, and what does it apply to?

Comment: I think this is another 'feature' in the game that doesn't quite work correctly. I've seen brand new gyms with battles won:1, I've also never seen a gym with more than 1 win.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This designated how many battles this Pokémon has won. In other words how many times it has successfully defended an attacker.

For further clarification, based on personal experience, I have only seen it pop up for Pokémon that took down my last Pokémon in my party when I was attacking a gym.

A few sources that back this:

> Pokémon also display a "Battles Won: X" number that shows how many times that specific Pokémon has stopped an attacker -[source](http://101pokemongo.com/wiki/Gyms)
>
> For each Battle Won, it means that your Pokemon was responsible for them losing the fight. That means their final attacking Pokemon was defeated by your guy. -[source](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/Q-A/what-does-battles-won-mean)

**Update:** a change to gyms may have changed how this works. According to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6m0psw/battles_won_is_not_battles_won_by_that_specific/?ref=share&ref_source=link),

> I'm not sure if this is widely known, but the "Battles Won" that shows up on the pre-battle splash screen is not how many times that attacker was the victorious Pokemon when you defeated another Pokemon. It is actually how many times that attacker was part of a team that defeated a defending Pokemon. I noticed this because a Machamp I just caught from a raid had 15 victories this morning and I was pretty sure I hadn't used it that many times already. The 15 victories, though, referred to the 5 Pokemon I had beaten in a gym 3 times each last night even though I didn't use Machamp for each individual fight.

however, this is the only source I can find noting this change, and have not been able to confirm this myself.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, I've placed a Pokemon in the gym and when I looked at it, it has said 2 battles won. I think it may be how many times you've succesfully attacked a gym or something but that doesn't sound right either so I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Aequitas maybe it was coincidence then, I will test some more and update this answer accordingly. I have placed a Pokemon that I attacked a gym with and won with in a gym and it didn't have this.

Comment: @Aequitas have you ever placed that Pokémon in a gym before (defending)?

Comment: @Aequitas The counter seems to be permanently tied to the pokemon itself. I have a slowbro with "battles won: 2", and I see it every time I put him in a gym, regardless of how long he's been in one for.

Comment: This no longer the case, as of a few months ago.

Comment: You took the link and quote from my answer... but anyways, due to the sheer amount of agreement with that post (500 something upvotes) as well as from personal experience with the "Battles Won" stat increasing extremely quickly, I am pretty certain that this is the case.

Comment: @Vemonus, i actually did not see your updated answer, i just saw your comment and this was the only source I could find noting the change. I didn't mean to steal your answer, only update mine so that the accepted answer had the correct information

Answer (score 5):

As of the gym rework a few months ago, the Battles Won stat no longer refers to the number of attacking teams a Pokémon has stopped (by defeating the sixth Pokémon).

Prior to the update, Pokémon would rarely get into the double digits for their Battles Won stat due to the fact that trainers rarely let their teams be wiped out completely (to save face or to save revives), however, they now very easily reach triple-digit scores. This is because the Battles Won stat now refers to the number of defending Pokémon defeated while a specific Pokémon was in the attacking party. If you take down a full gym from maximum CP (defeat all Pokémon 4 times), then all Pokémon on your team will have their Battles Won stat raised by 24.

From [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6m0psw/battles_won_is_not_battles_won_by_that_specific/):

> I'm not sure if this is widely known, but the "Battles Won" that shows up on the pre-battle splash screen is not how many times that attacker was the victorious Pokemon when you defeated another Pokemon. It is actually how many times that attacker was part of a team that defeated a defending Pokemon. I noticed this because a Machamp I just caught from a raid had 15 victories this morning and I was pretty sure I hadn't used it that many times already. The 15 victories, though, referred to the 5 Pokemon I had beaten in a gym 3 times each last night even though I didn't use Machamp for each individual fight.

Answer (score 2):

I have put in a Pokémon and had a friend attack the gym and lose on purpose to see if the number goes up and it doesn't. So I don't think it has to do with defenses wins. Also have used a single Pokémon to take over a gym and then placed the same Pokémon in the gym and it hasn't changed. I'm sure it used to work when the game first came out but most likely no longer works just like the paw prints.

Comment: How quickly did you check this information? Remember that the PoGo servers are not amazing...

Comment: Any time I check it doesn't change.

Comment: were you and your friend on the same team?

Comment: If you are on the same team, the number won't increase since instead of battling, you are training the gym.

Answer (score 2):

It only applies to defenses won, but I know that it doesnt count if the attacker runs out of time or flees the battle, you have to actually wipe out the opponents team. Only the pokemon that delivers the final blow will get credit. The most I had ever seen on one pokemon was 8 until I took a look at my wigglytuff and saw 122 wins somehow. That thing's the pokemon equivalent of the monty python killer rabbit. I nicknamed it Ares after the greek god of war to honor his fluffy pink combat skills.

Answer (score -1):

It's when a single Pokemon takes a gym with no help of the other 5 chosen.