# Does "Battles Won" accumulate per gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know from **[this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277731/what-does-battles-won-refer-to)** that "Battles Won" refers to the number of times your Pokemon has defended against an attacker at a Gym.

But I put my Pokemon in a Gym and immdietly I saw I already had 1 battle won, but no battle had taken place since I put it in the Gym.

Does this number **reset** ever? I *did* have this Pokemon in this same Gym earlier in the day. Will this number stay the same for ***each** Gym* or for ***all** Gyms*?

It's hard to see from this image, because the buttons literally hide the number but it says:

> BATTLES WON: 1

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be tied to the pokémon itself, rather than anything relating to what gym it's in. I have a Slowbro with "Battles won: 2", and that message immediately appears in *any* gym I put it in. There doesn't seem to be any way to view this number in the summary page, however.