# How does the 'battles won' work after June 2017 gym update?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the new gym system right before you start a battle against a defending Pokémon with with your own it shows the two Pokémon, their respective combat powers and battles won. How does the new battles won accumulate? Obviously every battle won increases the number, but do battles won when attacking and defending count? If a defending Pokémon beats multiple Pokémon in a row will it count as one or multiple battles and vice versa for attacking Pokémon? Do defeating raid Pokémon count? Also is the count still unique to a Pokémon when it is evolved?

The question is different from the former gym system ([What does "Battles Won" refer to?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277731/what-does-battles-won-refer-to)) because it showed only the battles won by a defender when it defended a certain gym the time it was undefeated. Then a good gym could have Pokémon with about at best over 10 battles won. Now I've seen Pokémon with battles won count exceeding 900! Also when I attacked a gym every time my own Pokémon defeated the gym Pokémon the count went up.

Comment: [Meta discussion regarding this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12611/127901)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on personal experience (and your own, it sounds like), the Battles Won stat now refers to the number of times it has been on an attacking team that has defeated a Pokémon in gym battles. This number used to represent how many times it defeated the last Pokémon of an attacking player's entire team it defeated, but this was changed during the gym rework.

From [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6m0psw/battles_won_is_not_battles_won_by_that_specific/):

> I'm not sure if this is widely known, but the "Battles Won" that shows up on the pre-battle splash screen is not how many times that attacker was the victorious Pokemon when you defeated another Pokemon. It is actually how many times that attacker was part of a team that defeated a defending Pokemon. I noticed this because a Machamp I just caught from a raid had 15 victories this morning and I was pretty sure I hadn't used it that many times already. The 15 victories, though, referred to the 5 Pokemon I had beaten in a gym 3 times each last night even though I didn't use Machamp for each individual fight.

Comment: Interesting, so defending victories do not count at all...

Comment: @Communisty I believe there's a "times defended" stat for defending victories that you can see when you have a Pokémon defend a gym, but iirc those victories are linked to specific gyms

Answer (score -3):

Actually no, I battled with my newly caught Kyogre for the first time on my team with my Rhydon (who schooled everyone btw) and the battles won never changed from zero.

Even after using Kyogre in a battle it did not change from zero.